# Kotlin: Expose composite class properties as public host class properties

Tags: kotlin, properties, composition, class-design

Say we have a `Composite` class

```
class Composite(val one: Int, val two: Int)
```

and a `Host` class

```
class Host(val comp: Composite)
```

Now we can print the properties of the `Composite` object

```
fun hostTest() {
    val comp = Composite(2, 3)
    val hst = Host(comp)

    println(hst.comp.one)
    println(hst.comp.one)
}
```

Is it possible in Kotlin to expose the `Composite` properties as direct properties of the `Host` class?
So, I want to write something like this:

```
fun hostTest() {
    val comp = Composite(2, 3)
    val hst = Host(comp)

    println(hst.one)
    println(hst.one)
}
```

Sure, one could create proxy properties in `Host` but I hope that Kotlin as a pragmatic language has direct support for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for this in Kotlin is [delegation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegation.html).

You can do it in a multitude of ways, and it depends on your needs which one you should choose. First you'll need an `interface` for your `Composite`:

```
interface Composite {
    val one: Int
    val two: Int
}
```

and a default implementation:

```
class DefaultComposite(override val one: Int,
                       override val two: Int) : Composite
```

Then you can use the `by` keyword to delegate to an instance of `Composite` from `Host`:

```
class Host(val composite: Composite) : Composite by composite
```

If you have sensible defaults for `composite`:

```
class CompositeWithDefaults(override val one: Int = 1,
                            override val two: Int = 2) : Composite
```

then you don't even have to pass `Composite` as a constructor parameter:

```
class Host() : Composite by CompositeWithDefaults()
```

or you can have its fields passed to `Host`:

```
class Host(one: Int, two: Int) : Composite by DefaultComposite(one, two)
```

or have a default value for it:

```
class Host(composite: Composite = CompositeWithDefaults()) : Composite by composite
```

Be careful though: *you shouldn't delegate to a property which is mutable, because the bytecode generated when using the `by` will use an internal field for your delegate and replacing the original object will have no effect*. I've written about this [here](http://the-cogitator.com/posts/blog/2018/09/29/by-the-way-exploring-delegation-in-kotlin.html#the-pitfall-of-interface-delegation).

This is how the generated Java code would look like if `composite` was a `var`:

```
public final class Host implements Composite {
   @NotNull
   private Composite composite;
   // $FF: synthetic field
   private final Composite $$delegate_0;

   @NotNull
   public final Composite getComposite() {
      return this.composite;
   }

   public final void setComposite(@NotNull Composite var1) {
      Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(var1, "<set-?>");
      this.composite = var1;
   }

   public Host(@NotNull Composite composite) {
      Intrinsics.checkParameterIsNotNull(composite, "composite");
      super();
      this.$$delegate_0 = composite;
      this.composite = composite;
   }

   public int getOne() {
      return this.$$delegate_0.getOne();
   }

   public int getTwo() {
      return this.$$delegate_0.getTwo();
   }
}
```

Note that the setter doesn't set `$$delegate_0`, but `composite`.

Comment: Thx, exactly what I need since my Composite is a 3rd party class with lots of properties which need to be wrapped.

Comment: I'm sorry to tell you, but your second link has died.

Answer (score 0):

It's not directly possible, but you can simulate it closely via [implementation by delegation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/delegation.html#implementation-by-delegation), which requires you to move the properties of `Composite` to an interface:

```
interface Composite {
    val one: Int
    val two: Int
}

class CompositeImpl(
    override val one: Int, 
    override val two: Int
) : Composite

class Host(val comp: Composite) : Composite by comp
```

<sup>[(runnable sample)](https://play.kotlinlang.org/#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)</sup>

You can make the `comp` property `private` if you need, or you may use any other instance of `Composite` that is available at the `Host`'s initialization time in the `Composite by ...` clause, even construct some `Composite` in-place.